# How to barplot using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe.

```
Store ID  Carwash
1            0
1            0
1            0
1            0
2            1
2            1
3            1
3            1
4            0
4            0
```

I want to plot the carwash according to store ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` along with [barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnGGO.png) from pandas

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['Store ID']).count()
car_wash = df.groupby(['Store ID']).apply(lambda x: x['Carwash'].unique())
car_wash = [list(i) for i in car_wash]
ax = df2.plot(kind='bar')
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(car_wash.pop(0)), (p.get_x()*1.005, p.get_height()*1.005))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to plot the value i.e. 1 or 0 instead of plotting the frequencies?

Comment: I am sorry, can you elaborate a little bit

Comment: I want to plot the value of carwash i.e. 1 or 0 of the store ID.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?